# how to create sitemap.xml file in joomla website?

Tags: sitemap, web.sitemap

First I created sitemap.xml file for my website and upload this file into the domain root folder of my site and Second I verified my website on webmaster of Google. 
But sitemap is not showing on my website. Please give me reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

Sitemap couldn't be displayed from xml file.

You need to install a component to help you create it. A very good one is: [Xmap](http://www.jooxmap.com/)